# Search for index value in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for setting different conditions depending on the index value.

I have the following indices values:

```
country

Uk
Us
Es
In
It
Ge
Ho
```

where country is an index in my dataframe.
I would need to do the following

- if index value is equal to 'Uk' then do something;
- if index value is equal to 'Us' then do something else;

and so on.

I have tried as follows

```
 if df.index.isin(['Us']) or df.isin(['Uk']):
        stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
    if df.index.isin(['Es']):
        stop_words = stopwords.words('spanish')
```

but it is the wrong approach. I am not familiar with indices in pandas dataframe as I have always used column.
Help and suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the index of your dataframe using `.loc()`

```py
df.loc['US', 'stop_words'] = 'english'
df.loc['UK', 'stop_words'] = 'english'
df.loc['ES', 'stop_words'] = 'spanish'
```

this example will create a new column `stop_words` with english or spanish depending on the index.

Comment: thank you Ippolito. I do not need to create a new column, just define separately list of stopwords to use later. Would it be possible to group together UK and US or I need to do it separately?

Comment: I got this error: TypeError: Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key

Comment: he means `loc` instead of `iloc`: `df.loc[['US','UK'], 'stop_words'] = 'english'`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @QuangHoang. I am getting this new error: `ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` Should I put any() at the end of `df.loc['US']`? I would prefer to not create a new column for stopwords.

Comment: There are several topics on this `truth value` things. In short, you should not do `if some_series or some_series` as you do in your code. The reason is that `if`, as a Python statement only accepts a single boolean, so it won't check for individual rows/cells in your series.

Comment: Thank you @QuangHoang. So this is the reason why Ippolito was suggesting to create new columns rather than use an if condition? When I filter my original dataset, I have only one of those country codes, e.g. `US` so I would need to consider all the options. I cannot create new columns for all countries code, as if I filter `US` I will not have any index with `Uk` or `Es`. This is the reason why I have been using if

Comment: A simple `df.loc[['US', 'UK']]` would give you all rows indexed by `US` and `UK`. If it’s not what you want, you need to update your question with more details of what you want.